# Just partially creation of csv file using crontab command

Tags: bash

I have some problem in automation the generation of a csv file. The bash code used to produce the csv works in parallel using 3 cores in order to reduce the time consumption; initially different csv files are produced, which are subsequently combined to form a single csv file. The core of the code is this cycle:

```
...
        waitevery=3

                for j in `seq 1 24`; do

                if((j==1)); then
                printf '%s\n' A B C D E | paste -sd ',' >> code${namefile}01${rr}.csv       
                fi
                j=$(printf "%02d" $j)

                ../src/thunderstorm --mask-file=mask.grib const_${namefile}$j${rr}.grib surf_${namefile}$j${rr}.grib ua_${namefile}$j${rr}.grib hl_const.grib out &      

                if ! ((c % waitevery)); then
                wait
                fi
                c=$((c+1))

            done
...
```

where `../src/thunderstorm` is a .F90 code which produce the second and successive files. 
If I run this code manually it produces the right csv file, but if I run it by a programmed crontab command it generates a csv file with the only header `A B C D E`

Some suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Use tag fortran for Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one old obsolete version.

Comment: Is that the entire script? You should add `#!/bin/bash` else `cron` may be running a plain bourne shell. (Not sure off hand if you have anything bash specific there, but it cant hurt)

Answer (score 1):

cron runs your script in an environment, that often does not match your expectations.

check that the `PATH` is correct and that the script is called from the correct location: `../src` is obviously relative, but to what?

I find cron-scripts to be much more reliable when using full paths for input, output and programs.

Answer (score 1):

As @umläute points out, *cron* runs your scripts but does not run the typical initiallizations that you may have when you open a terminal session. Which means that you have to make no assumptions regarding your environment.

For scripts that may be invoked from the shell and may be invoked from *cron* I usually add at the beginning something like this:

```
BIN_DIR=/home/myhome/bin
PATH=$PATH:$BIN_DIR
```

Also, make sure you do not use relative paths to executables like `../src/thunderstorm`. The working directory of the script invoked by *cron* may not be what you think. You may use `$BIN_DIR/../src/thunderstorm`. If you want to save typing add the relevant directories to the `PATH`.

The same logic goes for all other shell variables.

Doing a good initialization at the beginning of your script will allow you to run it from the shell for testing (or manual execution) and then run it as a *cron* job too.